# How to access all the files(pdf, doc etc) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I find out programmatically all the files present in iOS device and list them out to user? Also I need to download the file in my local application database?

How this can be achieved with Objective-C.

Comment: You have no access to files outside your app bundle

Comment: Your only option is to use files stored in iCloud drive using [`UIDocumentPickerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access all files in an iOS device outside the sandbox of the app. But there are other ways you can achieve this. What you can do is:

- Access all the files in Gallery using UIImagePickerController.
- Access all the user files in network- Dropbox/Google drive/iCloud. They all have separate public APIs that can be downloaded and used to download/upload files in network.

In this way, you can access most of the user files and use the same in your application.

Comment: any sample app for iCloud, Dropbox, Google drive integration?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : you can't (on a non-jailbroken device).

Each app is launched is in own sandbox and can't interact with the others apps, expect using API provided by Apple for app-communication (ex: extension)

You should look at that [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html) about App Sandboxing, which is valid for OSX and iOS apps.

The main difference between these two OS, as quoted directly from the doc :

> **iOS Note**: Because it is not for user documents, an OS X container
>   differs from an iOS container—which, in iOS, is the one and only
>   location for user documents. In addition, an iOS container contains
>   the app itself. This is not so in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access all the files outside the app sandbox. But, if they are available at some shared location(network), you can use third party libraries to access them. For eg. 
1. For iCloud- iOS provides inbuilt framework of UIDocument
2. For dropbox- DropBoxAPI is available
3. For Google drive- there is a separate library to access files in the drive.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: By UIDocument we can access from iCloud?